# Can't get CSS3 selectors to work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to learn the new CSS3 selectors and so have tried the following code:

```
<body class="frontpage">
    <section name="top">
        <header class="head" name="top">
            <div id="my-name">
                <h1 id="title">
                    Josh Dempsey
                </h1>
            </div>
        </header>   
    </section>
</body>
```

With the CSS:

```
body[class*="f"]>section[name$="op"]>header[class|top]>div[id*="my"]>h1[id=title]{color:white;}
```

I would expect my name to be printed in white, not black/auto.

My other CSS in case anyone can find anything out from it:

```
body[class*="fro"]{background-color:#f8efe1;height:auto;width:auto;direction:ltr;z-     index:1;}
section[name*="t"]{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100px;}
header[class$="ad"]{background-color:#272727;height:100%;width:100%;}
h1[class="title-of-site"]{color:white;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-  weight:300;margin:0}
header[class$="op"]>div[name*=image_holder]  {position:absolute;top:5px;left:10%;bottom:5px;height:40px;width:40px;background-color:
transparent;}
```

I have checked all of this on W3.org and have successfully validated it. So I am stumped by this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong, but never come across this before, header[class|top]  what does it selects?

Comment: You've got some mental CSS going on. Looks like you're over complicated it big time. Why not use regular selectors like body.frontpage or header.head?

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing it in?

Comment: By the way, it would be very easy to test which bit of your mega selector is broken, simply by removing one bit of at a time from the fromt. Keep removing bits one by one; when it starts working you'll have found the bit that was broken.

Comment: Also by the way, I agree with @Coop; you should definitely try to simplify your selectors. There's nothing wrong with using `[class*=]` etc, but over-use of these complex selectors - especially the ones with wildcards - will very likely give you performance issues. In general, use of wildcards should be the exception; use them sparingly. In most cases you'd be far better off simply having a simple class to select.

Comment: `header[class|top]` [doesn't do what you think it does](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attrnmsp), and for that reason you cannot possibly have validated it successfully.

Comment: @Ruben Serrate Pardo: See the link in my above comment.

Comment: @BoltClock Cheers! So that would match any element within the "class" namespace that contains an attribute named top?

Comment: @Ruben Serrate Pardo: More precisely, an element that contains an attribute in that namespace, named `top`. The element itself does not necessarily have to belong to that namespace.

Comment: Thanks guys, you're right, normally I would just use a normal class or ID to get the job done, but the aim of this mission was to learn the more complicated selectors. Thanks for everyone who has commented. It's appreciated big time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had a few syntax issues in the selector (mainly quotations around the values).

The reason the selector wasn't working was you had `header[class|top]` pointing to the wrong attribute, as header had `class="head"`. You need to change that to name and put an equals after the vertical line.

```
header[name|="top"]
```

This is the full selector working below:

```
body[class*="f"] > section[name$="op"] > header[name|="top"] > div[id*="my"] > h1[id="title"]
{
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: The missing or inconsistent quotations around the values aren't a problem, but it does help to be consistent.

Comment: Consistency is king! If you get used to putting correct syntax now as a beginner, your life becomes alot easier later on when you move to stricter languages

Comment: Welcome to the site by the way - I see you're off to a great start already!

Answer (score 2):

Replace `header[class|top]` to `header[class|name="top"]`.

Comment: That's still wrong. See http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attrnmsp for what this syntax really means.

Answer (score 1):

You could try replacing the 'class' with 'id' on h1. Also, change `h1[class="title-of-site"]` to `h1[id="title"]`.

See this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iVeqexo/1/).